# Search large data in the react native list-view

Tags: javascript, listview, reactjs, react-native, hybrid-mobile-app

I have 9000 offline records in the list-view of react native app,I want to add search filter without affecting performance of the application .Please suggest me what approach I should adopt to search the large local data.

Comment: where the data are stored ? AsyncStorage ?

Comment: Since the data is offline, is it correct to assume that it is static?

Comment: yes data stored in asynStorage @Ludovic

Comment: @D-reaper I'm saving data in the variable from the AsynchStorage

Comment: If your are looking for text filter : Possible duplicate of [How to filter data in ListView React-native?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42644161/how-to-filter-data-in-listview-react-native)

Comment: Yes I'm looking for the text filter ,but for the 9000 records with smooth performance, sorry @Ludovic mentioned  solution is not relevant

Comment: @MobileSafaltek No problem, it's just to be sure!

Answer (score 1):

If your really need great performances, you should try Realm Database.

Maybe it's not a proper answer because you are not asking for a new DB mechanisms but I think it's the way to go.

However, a React native version is out (V1.0) and do a better job than AsyncStorage. Then you can make very complex queries like SQL and handle relations betweens datas.

[image]

More informations and benchmarks : https://realm.io/news/introducing-realm-react-native/

Comment: Thanks @Ludovic Actually my concern is related to the list search filter performance

Comment: Yea my answer is not precise enough, Realm have his own ListView that react to DB changes